# Show alert() after executing managed bean action method

Tags: jsf, alert, facelets

I've a command link:

```
<h:commandLink value="Delete"
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" 
    action="#{bean.deleteDestination(destination, '/destination/show')}" />
```

It invokes this managed bean action method:

```
public String deleteDestination(Destination selected, String action) {
    List<Flight> flights = getEjbFlightFacade().findFlightWithDestination(selected);

    if (flights.isEmpty()) {
        getEjbDestinationFacade().remove(selected);
        setDestinations(getEjbDestinationFacade().findAll());
    }
    else {
        // Here need to show an alert() that user can't remove the item.
    }

    return action;
}
```

As indicated by the comment, I'd like to show an `alert()` that the enduser can't remove the item. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let JSF conditionally render the desired script based on a bean property.

E.g.

```
this.undeleteable = true;
```

```
<h:outputScript rendered="#{bean.undeleteable}">
    alert("You can't delete it.");
</h:outputScript>
```

The canonical way, however, is to just show a (global) faces message.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("You can't delete it."));
```

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

Alerts are namely soo 1990.